# Illustrator lines (strokes) became thin

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was trying to edit a circle and all my previous lines became thin.

When I hover the mouse over them the stroke weight reads as unchanged.

Anybody who can help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell I think you switched to outline mode.

[image]

hitting cmd / ctrl + y should turn things back to normal.